# File access issue in unit test running some test cases

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have a concurrency issue in my test's arrange block, where I do create some files in a subfolder(IO exception on file access in some test case runs). I have a parameterized test and test cases seems to run in parallel despite `[NonParallelizable]` attribute.

The issue is observed on tests run in Test-Explorer of VS2019.

Is there a possibility to prevent a parallel execution of test cases for some tests, it would be nice, if another tests(not test cases) in the fixture could still run in parallel.

```
[TestFixture]
public class ClassToTest_Fixture
{
    [TestCase("SubFolder", new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" })]
    [TestCase("SubFolder", new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" })]
    [TestCase("SubFolder", new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" })]
    [TestCase("SubFolder", new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" })]
    [TestCase("SubFolder", new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" })]
    [NonParallelizable] //Doesn't help
    public void TestMethod(string folder, string[] files)
    {
        #region Arrange
        var fldr = Path.Combine(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory, folder);
        if(!Directory.Exists(fldr))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(fldr);
        }
        foreach(var fn in files)
        {
            File.Create(Path.Combine(fldr, fn));
        } 
        #endregion Arrange

        //Act
        //Assert
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestMethodCanBeRunInParallel( )
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what happens when you run the tests. If you are running under the console runner, use the --labels option so you can see when each test starts and stops. As for the second part of your question... all the test cases must be either parallel or non-parallel. Use a different method if you want one of them to be different.

Comment: @Charlie I have an IO Exception _".. File in use by another Process"_ by some test cases, not by all. Posted code should produce an error. So I don't want to have some "test cases" to be executed in parallel and some sequentially, but to control it on test level(not on testfixture or "test case" level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I have a concurrency issue .... test cases seems to run in parallel*** was a wrong assumption, which I have made intuitively. After I have added an output with a time stamps and `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` I have found that testcases do run non parallel even without `[NonParallelizable]` attribute.

The issue was (my bad), that I haven't payed enough attention to the return value of `File.Create(fileName)`, which is a `FileStream`.
Since I have not disposed a `FileStream` I had issues (IO exceptions) with next test case run.

Adding `FileStream.Close()` has solved the issue:

```
...
File.Create(Path.Combine(fldr, fn))?.Close();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: This doesn't work currently, see https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/3371

More...

Since the operation of `ParallelizableAttribute` is always in relation to the parallel status of higher level tests (fixtures, namespaces, assembly), you should specify in the question whether the attribute is used on the fixture, the assembly or a setupfixture in the same namespace. I'm assuming that there are must be some higher level setting, otherwise you would not need to use `[NonParallelizable]` here, but I don't know what that setting is. :-) I'll edit this if you clarify it.

A similar problem arises when you want the individual cases to run in parallel, when the higher-level setting is non-parallel. That's easily resolved using ``` [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]``.  m Unfortunately, the ``` NonParallelizableAttribute`doesn't take a scope argument and is simply a synonym for`[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Nonein)]`. I think that was a mistake in my original design and maybe it will be corrected by the current team in a future release.

Workarounds...

1. The simplest thing would be to make the fixture containing these methods non-parallelizable. This may or may not be possible, depending on the details of your application, whether you have parameterized fixtures, etc. You could also try `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixture)]` on the fixture. That's supposed to allow the fixture, but not its children, to run in parallel.
2. More complicated and maybe confusing to your team... Add another fixture class and mark it `[NonParallelizable]`. You can nest it if you like, but do not derive it from the first class, since that will cause all the contained tests to run twice. Copy the method into the new class along with all the cases, which may not be run in parallel.

If it were my problem, I'd lean toward the first method, even though there's a bit of a performance hit. Developer time is generally what you want to optimize in test-writing, at least until you actually measure a significant problem.

Then, you can wait to see what the next NUnit release brings. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the issue was by my side. See my answer. Helpful advice was _" so you can see when each test starts and stops"_ in your comment.